# Sproutcore SC.MenuPane keep/remember/visible selected item

Tags: sproutcore, sproutcore-views

I have a working popup button with menu 2 options, and need to 'keep/remember' the selected item visible to the user, in other words, the next time the menu pops up, the previous made choice should be visible (eg highlighted).

```
selectMenuButton: SC.PopupButtonView.extend({
                    layout: {left:10, bottom: 10, height: 18, width:100},
                    controlSize: SC.SMALL_CONTROL_SIZE,
                    title: 'Menu',
                    menu: SC.MenuPane.extend({
                      layout: { width: 150 },
                      items: [
                      { title: 'option1', checkbox: YES, action: 'action1',target: 'App.Controller1'},
                      { title: 'option2', checkbox: NO, action: 'action2',target: 'App.Controller2'}
                      ]
                    }),
                }),
```

I tried classnames css .active or .sel, but that didn't work.
Please some advice, thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you use an SC.SelectView ?

Comment: In the meantime I did use a SC.SelectView in combination binding and a observer, the observer execute the required action. One little problem occurred, when a user clicks on the same menu item the observer does nothing, and I need to execute the action always. Tips?

Comment: Solved, I set the property to null after usage, so it is always a change in the SC.SelectView item.

Comment: @fpk Can you make this into a real answer?

Comment: @Maurits, I really do not know if it is a correct solution, and I am still looking for the observer question, that is, I want the action always, not only on a changed value. The setter has side effects, executing twice and a lost selectedItem checkbox.